# Laravel Query Builder - where clause equals anything programmatically

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.6 - Query Builder.

Is it possible to make a query builder where statement that a value equals everything programmatically?

Let's say that I have this code:

```
$foo = 1;

DB::table('users')
  ->select('*')
  ->where('status', '=', $foo)
  ->get();
```

If `$foo = 1` then it's straightforward. The query will select everything with the status of 1.

**Q:** Is it possible to assign something to the `$foo` variable so the select query returns every record regardless of the status from the DB?

Of course, I can make it happen with 2 query statements like this:

```
$foo = 1;

if ($foo === null) {
  DB::table('users')
    ->select('*')
    ->get();
} else {
  DB::table('users')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('status', '=', $foo)
    ->get();
}
```

However, I'm looking for a shorter / more effective solution. Is it possible somehow - without using `raw code` inside the Where statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```php
$query = DB::table('users')->select('*');

// $foo = 'get it...';

if ($foo) {
    $query->where('status', $foo);
}

$result = $query->get();
```

Or even more `laravel-ish`:

```
$result = DB::table('users')->select('*')
          ->when($foo, function ($query) use ($foo) {
              return $query->where('status', $foo);
          })
          ->get();
```

[Check more here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#conditional-clauses)

Comment: It is interesting that in the documentation the `$foo` variable is passed to the callback function through the `use` statement like you do, while the [implementation already passes the variable as second argument to the callback](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php#L88). Very interesting function though, just learned something. :)

Comment: Thank you so much for this both answers are perfect solutions. Nice to know multiple workarounds for different situations.